# Arreglos de JavaScript llaves {} vs corchetes [] ¿Cuál es la diferencia?

Tags: javascript, jquery, array

¿Cuál es la diferencia entre cada una de las siguientes definiciones de matriz?

```
var myArray = [];
var myArray = new Array();
var myArray = {};
```

Y en que casos es recomendable aplicar cada uno de ellos.

Comment: Los únicos arrays que existen allí es la primera y segunda variable, la tercera es un objeto

Comment: La diferencia es que `{}` se usa para definir Objetos y `[]` se usa para Arrays. Aparte de eso, ¿cuál es la duda? Saludos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tratando de responder por partes:

### Primera duda

> ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre cada una de las siguientes definiciones de matriz?

**Objeto - Array:** En arreglo es una lista con índice numérico (generalmente consecutivo) y es iterable, es decir, puede recorrerse con métodos específicos como [.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

Puedes declarar con corchetes o instanciando la clase:

```
let arr1 = [];
let arr2 = new Array();
```

Hay diferencias mínimas entre ambas declaraciones, pero creo no son tan importantes y no merece la pena comentar, más allá de que es más sencillo, legible y breve la notación con corchetes.

La mayoría de las veces, todos los elementos de un arreglo son del mismo tipo, pero eso no es una regla, simplemente es la forma en que muchos acostumbramos a trabajar.

**Objeto:** Un objeto creado con llaves debe contener pares `nombre_de_propiedad: 'Valor'` y no son iterables, es decir, no hay métodos propios para recorrer como se hace con los arreglos, aunque siempre puedes recurrir a otras formas.

El valor para cada propiedad puede ser de cualquier tipo.

```
let obj = {
    propiedadUno: 'Valor 1',
    propiedadDos: ['Uno', 'Dos', 'Tres'],
    propiedadTres: {
        subPropiedad: 'Otro valor'
    }
};
```

### Segunda duda

> ¿Y en que casos es recomendable aplicar cada uno de ellos?

Depende de tus necesidades: si quieres recorrer, filtrar, reducir, etc., entonces se recomienda un arreglo. Si quieres acceder a propiedades por nombre, entonces un objeto.

Lo mejor es que puedes combinar, teniendo arreglos de objetos y objetos donde las propiedades sean arreglos u otros objetos.

#### Algunos ejemplos simples

**Días de la semana:** Un arreglo es muy adecuado:

```
let dias = ['Dom', 'Lun', 'Mar', 'Mie', 'Jue', 'Vie', 'Sab'];
// Mostrar un día específico, por índice numérico (0 a 6)
console.log(dias[4]); // Jue
// Recorrer con forEach para mostrar todos
dias.forEach(dia => console.log(dia));
// Recorrer con ciclo for
for(let i = 0; i < dias.length; i++) {
    console.log(dias[i]);
}
```

**Lista de usuarios con nombre, apellido y correo electrónico**

**Opción 1:** Con arreglo donde cada elemento es otro arreglo:

```
let users = [
    ['John', 'Doe', 'john@doe.com'],
    ['Jane', 'Doe', 'jane@doe.com']
];
// Mostrar apellido del primer usuario (elemento cero)
console.log(users[0][1]);
```

**Opción 2:** Con arreglo donde cada elemento es un objeto:

```
let users = [
    { nombre: 'John', apellido: 'Doe', correo: 'john@doe.com' },
    { nombre: 'Jane', apellido: 'Doe', correo: 'jane@doe.com' }
];
// Mostrar correo del segundo usuario (elemento uno)
console.log(users[1].correo);
```

Como puedes ver, en las dos opciones anteriores, los datos son los mismos, pero la estructura y acceso es diferente

**Uso de objetos:** Podrías usar los objetos como un diccionario:

```
let frutas = {
    apple: 'Manzana',
    orange: 'Naranja'
};
```

También son ideales para guardar información específica como datos personales, opciones de configuración o cualquier otro donde solo requieras acceder con objeto y nombre de propiedad; con el ejemplo de las frutas:

```
console.log(frutas.apple);
```

Answer (score 2):

Las llaves se usan para declarar un objeto (clase Object).
Los corchetes se usan para declarar un array (clase Array).
El constructor `Array()` sin parámetros es equivalente a simplemente poner `[]`. Generalmente se usa `[]` por prevedad.

```js
let test1= {};
let test2= [];
let test3= new Array();

console.log(test1 instanceof Array);
console.log(test2 instanceof Array);
console.log(test3 instanceof Array);
```

En un array añades valores en un cierto orden:

```js
let array= ['a','b','c'];

console.log(array[0],array[1],array[2])
```

En un objeto has de definir el nombre, clave o identificador para cada valor:

```js
let objeto = {
  saludo: 'Hola',
  despedida: 'adiós'
};

console.log(objeto.saludo, objeto.despedida);
```

Answer (score 2):

Tienes una mala concepción de un arreglo y un objeto. La diferencia básica es que el arreglo es posicional y el objeto es clave-valor.

Al array puedes acceder mediante índices, pero no por una "palabra"

```
const myArr = [ 1, 2, 3 ];
console.log( myArr[ 1 ] );
// Output: 2
console.log( myArr[ 'foo' ] )
// Output: undefined
```

Al Objeto accedes mediante una clave, por lo general una palabra o letra

```
const myObj = { 
  foo: 'this is foo', 
  bar: 'this is bar' 
};

console.log( myObj[ 'foo' ] );
// Output: this is foo

console.log( myObj.foo )
// Output: this is foo

console.log( myObj[0] )
// Output: undefined
```

Puedes acceder mediante un número, pero es muy raro y mala práctica declarar un objeto por números, pierde su esencia.

```
const myObj = { 
  0: 'this is zero', 
};
console.log( myObj[0] )
// Output: this is zero
```

Ahora, `new Array()` y `[]` difiere en cómo lo crea el intérprete, además, si de pura casualidad sobreescribes la función, se perdera así `function Array(){}` Es mucho más eficiente usar corchetes y más limpio.

```
const myArr    = [3] // myArr.length == 1, myArr[0] == 3
const myNewArr = new Array(3), // myNewArr.length == 3, myNewArr[0] == undefined
```

Comment: Gracias por la aclaración realmente si estaba un poco confundido entre la diferencia básica de un arreglo y un objeto.